PWA push notifications not working on iOS Safari (but working on android, web, mac os safari)
I have NextJS PWA app and I configured it with VAPID and web-push (nodejs). The notification pops up on all other devices (android, web, mac safari) but not on iphone with safari.
Extra details:

I have tried two different phones: not working
iOS version: 17.4
yes, i've added the PWA to my home screen

The weird thing is that I do get the push event. So the worker.js is working fine. But the problem is when showing the popup e.g. self.registration.showNotification. I have tried a lot of things and have been stuck with this.
Did anyone else experience this?
======== Code details below
This is how my next.config.js is configured:
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

const withPWA = require('next-pwa')( {
    dest: "public",
    sw: "sw.js",
    register: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
    disable: isDev
  });

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = withPWA(nextConfig);


How I'm setting the VAPID details:
webpush.setVapidDetails(
        "mailto:myemail@mydomain.so",
        vapidKeys.publicKey,
        vapidKeys.privateKey
    );

This is what my worker.js looks like:
self.addEventListener("push", async (e) => {
    try {
        const { message, body, icon } = JSON.parse(e.data.text());

         // Notify the main thread to play sound
        const clients = await self.clients.matchAll();
        clients.forEach(client => {
            client.postMessage({
                type: 'PLAY_SOUND'
            });
        });

        e.waitUntil(
            self.registration.showNotification(message)
        );

       
    } catch (error) {
        // Send error log to the main thread
        self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
            clients.forEach(client => {
                client.postMessage({
                    type: 'ERROR',
                    message: `Error in push event: ${error.message}`
                });
            });
        });
    }
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients.matchAll({
            type: "window",
        }).then((clientList) => {
            for (const client of clientList) {
                if (client.url === "/" && "focus" in client)
                    return client.focus();
            }
            if (clients.openWindow) return clients.openWindow("/");
        })
    );
});

I have tried on two different iphone devices. I have tried on android (works), tried on mac os (works).
I have tried to debug the Safari context on iOS. I can see that sw.js is loaded properly and the console logs work (it even triggers a custom event I used to debug)
But I think the problem lies with showNotification which I can't figure out why.

You need to have a manifest.json file in your public folder. Also, don't forget to add it in the head tag in your layout.tsx file.
I have a working version of the app here.
code:
https://github.com/david-randoll/push-notification-nextjs
live demo:
https://push-notification.davidrandoll.com/
Don't forget to Add to home on iPhones.
